# svn+ssh:// keep tunnel open

Tags: svn, ssh, tunnel

I am using a program that uses svn extensively, but for every file that it checks out it opens a new svn+ssh session. I am connecting to a server that only supports svn+ssh, no other protocol.

I was thinking of setting up an SSH tunnel before using svn (svn://svn.cern.ch/....)
I don't want to use a proxy server, but I want to create the ssh tunnel using the svn server itself.
What is the ssh tunnel equivalent command for:

```
svn co svn+ssh://user@svn.cern.ch/reps/....
```

I think it should be something like:

```
ssh user@svn.cern.ch -L 3690:svn.cern.ch:3690 -fN
svn co svn://localhost/reps/...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with opening a new connection for each svn session?

Comment: @Kenster - for each **file** in transaction

Comment: Can you see and check server's config? No, you commands are  (at some aspects) wrong (using svn+ssh: does **not** mean you have plian ssh-shell *for the same user*)